# Icinga (nagios) ignoring forced checks

Tags: nagios, icinga

I have a strange problem: Icinga (nagios) doesn't run `check_nt` which I've set up on a debian box.

What I do is that I schedule a forced check of both `NSClient_version` and `PING`. If I look in the log file, I can see that both commands are scheduled to run:

```
[1372774536] EXTERNAL COMMAND: SCHEDULE_FORCED_SVC_CHECK;sqlnota03.dbb.dk;NSClient_version;1372781738
[1372774536] EXTERNAL COMMAND: SCHEDULE_FORCED_SVC_CHECK;sqlnota03.dbb.dk;PING;1372781738
```

After having switched on debugging, I get this:

```
[1372774536.502948] [016.2] [pid=3840] Found another service check event for service 'NSClient_version' on host 'sqlnota03.dbb.dk' @ Tue Jul  2 17:47:21 2013
[1372774536.502973] [016.2] [pid=3840] Keeping original service check event (ignoring the new one).
```

I've gone over the configuration many times and couldn't find any errors and Icinga reports that the configuration is ok when running `icinga -v <icinga.cfg>`.

Is there anyone who can spot what I am doing wrong?

The configuration is:

```
define host {
    use        windows-server
    host_name  <the host>
    address    192.168.1.61
    hostgroups mssql, termsrv, windows, nsclient_version
}

define service {
    use generic-service
    hostgroup_name nsclient_version
    service_description NSClient_version
    servicegroups nsclient_version
    check_command check_nt!CLIENTVERSION
}

# 'check_nt' command definition
define command {
    command_name    check_nt
    command_line    check_nt command_line /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nt -p12489 -s <snip> -H '$HOSTADDRESS$' -v '$ARG1$' '$ARG2' '$ARG3'
}
```

It seems that there is a service check stuck somewhere in the system that keeps Icinga from running a new one?!?

I've replaced the `check_nt` command that should be run with a small script that just touches a local file in `/tmp` to see if it is being run at all. This isn't the case.

*Edit*

I used the old nagios web interface to schedule a new check and (finally) got this:

```
Processing: 'SERVICE ALERT: sqlnota03.db
```

b.dk;NSClient_version;$SERVICESTATE$;$SERVICESTATETYPE$;$SERVICEATTEMPT$;The com
mand defined for service NSClient_version does not exist

Now I'm unsure what the message means - that the executable `check_nt` can't be found or something else...?

Comment: Did you try turning on debugging in the NSClient to see if it sheds any light?

Comment: No need to. The command is never executed. I also tried to fire up Wireshark and verified this - there is no communication at all. Running ``check_nt`` by hand works.

Answer (score 1):

I found the error.

It was a combination of two things:

- Icinga-web didn't schedule the checks properly. For some reason it just ignored the check command (I'll look into that later).
- Once I got a check scheduled, it was clear that the path to `command_line` parameter was wrong.

So I changed this:

```
command_line    check_nt command_line /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nt -p12489 -s <snip> -H '$HOSTADDRESS$' -v '$ARG1$' '$ARG2' '$ARG3'
```

To this:

```
command_line /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nt -p12489 -s <snip> -H '$HOSTADDRESS$' -v '$ARG1$' '$ARG2' '$ARG3'
```

I am surprised how much time it took to make Icinga run an actual check so I could diagnose the error.

Comment: Checking if commands are executed is targetted in various wiki articles. Also how to manually run those checks. https://wiki.icinga.org/display/testing/Icinga+Plugin+Testing